Mishneh Torah Editions: Mifal Mishneh Torah OR Steinsaltz Mishneh Torah
How does the Mifal Mishneh Torah compare to the Steinsaltz Mishneh Torah?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each edition?
Which edition is more accurate?
Do any of you have experience learning with both editions? If so, which one provides a clearer explanation of the Mishneh
Torah?
Which edition is more conducive to a daily study program?


I would also add Frenkel's Mishneh Torah if one needs all sources. Also Mishneh Torah Hashalem single volume which is useful for those who like to have sources at hand, although it has very small font.

There are also more glorious ones: Oz veHadar and Machon haMaor

related: Recommendation for edition of Mishne Torah with sources

I own both editions and learned from them. They both are beautifully produced, clearly typeset, and have made significant efforts to correct many of the mistakes that crept up in older editions. I do not know if one is more accurate than the other but doubt it is meaningful.
The Steinsaltz/Koren edition has a biur which explains complicated words and a very useful piskei v'shitot section which brings references to Shulchan Aruch (more rarely other texts, e.g., Aruch Hashulchan) and their psakim, sometimes references to the gemara. It includes the Raavad in normal-sized font as well. Each book is relatively thick and heavy but beautifully produced as everything Koren does.
The Mifal Mishne Torah exists in "brochure" format which makes it easier to transport/learn during travel, has a similar section explaining unclear words, and its particularity is that it uses other locations in the Rambam to explain them (i.e., it uses the Rambam as a commentary on the Rambam).
None of these editions bring the traditional commentaries, e.g., Kesef Mishne, Magid Mishne. As such they help understand the text but don't delve into its meaning.
I personally prefer the Steinsaltz edition when learning at a desk (because of the additional halacha section) and the Mifal MT if I want to take it somewhere.

That response is very helpful. Thank you. Do think the Mifal MT Torah edition has any advantages over the Steinsaltz edition?

And do you find that the Rambam according to the Rambam approach of Mifal MT results in significant differences between it and the Steinsaltz edition? I assume that R. Steinsaltz and his team were aware of what the Rambam wrote in Moreh Nevuchim and his other writings...

In practice I believe the main difference is the physical format. Steinsaltz is closer to a real (slightly heavy) book and is a pleasure to learn from aesthetically. Mifal MT is more convenient to transport but less pleasing to the eye. Content wise I very much like having the halacha on the page.

I assume you have seen the Koren sample: https://korenpub.com/cdn/shop/files/rambam_hahava_for_website.pdf?v=12893670995624531513

Yes, I've seen the samples of each. I am mainly looking to see if the content of each commentary has an advantage over the other.
